# Got an error when using increment variable name inside dplyr

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I got the following error, when i run the code : "Error: Column `col` is unknown".

```
for (col in names(test)) {

final  <-  test  %>% 
  group_by(col, "DT") %>%
  summarise(n = n())  
}
```

The test dataset looks like this:

[image]

col should be transactionId, then Product and each time i create frequency table with DT : transactionId*DT, Product*DT

Thank you

Comment: What is "DT" ? Can you add a reproducible example and show the expected output for the same?

Comment: I added a data and example

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it is better to get data in long format which avoids the using `for` loop. We can use `count` which is shortcut for `group_by` + `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%
  mutate_all(as.character) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -DT) %>%
  count(DT, value)
```

Comment: I got an error: Error in count(., DT, value) : object 'DT' not found

Comment: @Alexey `DT` is the column name that you have in the data. If it doesn't work then please share a reproducible example using `dput` and not as images. See [here on how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).